# How I can test this function in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, vitest

How I can mock this (crypto.subtle.digest) function, which I use in components. I use vitest and react-testing-library

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')
 ❯ Module.bgColorByEmail src/utils/bgColorByEmail.ts:4:36
      2|   const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      3|   const data = encoder.encode(email);
      4|   const hash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-384', data);
       |                                    ^
      5|   const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hash));
      6|   const hashHex = hashArray
 ❯ setColor src/features/user/AboutUser/AboutUser.tsx:36:27
 ❯ src/features/user/AboutUser/AboutUser.tsx:39:5
 ❯ commitHookEffectListMount node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23150:26
 ❯ commitPassiveMountOnFiber node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24931:11
 ❯ commitPassiveMountEffects_complete node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24891:9
 ❯ commitPassiveMountEffects_begin node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24878:7
 ❯ commitPassiveMountEffects node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24866:3
 ❯ flushPassiveEffectsImpl node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27039:3
 ❯ flushPassiveEffects node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26984:14

This error originated in "src/__tests__/AboutUser.test.tsx" test file. It doesn't mean the error was thrown inside the file itself, but while it was running.
The latest test that might've caused the error is "update user form must be in the document". It might mean one of the following:
- The error was thrown, while Vitest was running this test.
- This was the last recorded test before the error was thrown, if error originated after test finished its execution.

vi.mock('crypto.subtle.decrypt', async () => {
  return {
    ...vi.importMock('bgColorByEmail'),
    crypto: vi.fn(),
  };
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't just dump the error without saying what you are expecting and what have you tried. But,  your `TypeError` at hand it means `.subtle`property is `undefined` hence why you try to run that `digest` property doesn't exist in the value of `undefined`. You may use *optional chaining* but at that point your `hash` variable will be assigned with the `undefined` value. Are you sure you are *requiring* (*importing*) the `crypto` package inside your module?

Answer (score 0):

To mock crypto.subtle.digest function with vitest, you can use the following code:

```
vi.mock('crypto.subtle.digest', async () => new ArrayBuffer(32));
```

This creates a mock implementation of crypto.subtle.digest using vitest's mock function. The implementation returns a Promise that resolves to an ArrayBuffer with a length of 32.

You can place this code in a beforeEach block in your test file, so that the mock is applied to every test in that file.

Note that this mock implementation doesn't actually perform any hashing, it simply returns an empty ArrayBuffer. If you need to test your components with different hash values, you can modify the implementation to return different ArrayBuffer values based on the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node `crypto` lib. This is an example Jest test:

```js
import { webcrypto } from 'crypto';

describe('digest', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperties(global, {
      crypto: { value: webcrypto, writable: true }
    });
  });

  it('uses crypto', async () => {
    expect(await crypto.subtle.digest(...).toEqual(...);
  });
});
```